# Div jumps when using CSS animation cheat sheet

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I just added the [CSS animation cheat sheet](http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html) to my website. But now when I scroll down to the image I've implemented the animate on, the div expands to the bottom of the page. When the animation is finished the div size is normal again.

The page where it's happening: http://keessonnema.nl/

html:

```
<div class="wrapper portfolio">
    <span class="spacer"></span>

    <div id="pic-wrap">
    <img class="pic" src="http://multy-service.ru/media/pictures/imac-3.png" alt="Imac" width="450px"/>
    </div>

    <div class="text-wrap">
        <h1>
            Webdesign sample text
        </h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed ipsum blandit, tristique risus vel, volutpat rbi at lacus et dolor tincidunt pretium sollicitudin in leo.
            <a href="">Lees meer...></a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#pic-wrap{
float: right;
visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

jquery:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('.pic').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                $(this).addClass("slideUp");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to test it beacause i always have to refresh te page te see the effect, i can only guess what te problem could be.

Maybe its because your default (iMac) image is over 890px height. Try to add the image with a smaller height. Also you could try to set the div slide to overflow:hidden and a fixed height / or max-height.

EDIT:

Try

```
#slide5 {
z-index: 99999;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Your welcome! Good luck with futher development, the website looks nice!